# Copper reducer before hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water

My house copper lines are 3/4 in and my new water heater accepts 1/2 copper in a compression connection. Is there any issue with adding a 3/4 to 1/2 reducer before and after the heater?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: What type of water heater is this? I thought only point-of-use (POI) units were 1/2" or even 3/8", but pretty much any whole-house water heater would be 3/4"...

Comment: ECO 11 https://cdn.globalimageserver.com/FetchDocument.aspx?ID=CC0D6229-1B9C-4C01-82F6-4826FECCF363 "1/2 CF connection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing the math for the area A = πr2

- 1/2 inch pipe that is A = π(.25)^2
- 3/4 inch pipe that is A = π(.375)^2

You can see the difference in area and that changes the amount of volume that will flow. Your water heater has a flow rate based on its piping and therefore it will be the limiting factor. Your house could handle more.

The only problem I can foresee possibly happening and would be most likely after install is that your 3/4 pipes could have an air gap but this should dissipate over time by running the water slowly in order to fill the line and build pressure.